# Laravel data['title']

Tags: php, laravel

So i am trying to get a title and define this on my controllers but when i request the data['title'] it gets "1" and i set "Test".

My controller for my home

```
 Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

My line to set the $title

```
  $data['title']   = "Test";
  return view('home.home', $data);
```

My head.blade.php

```
  <title>{{ $title or Helpers::meta((!isset($exception)) ? Route::current()->uri() : '', 'title') }} {{ $additional_title or '' }}</title>
```

The laravel version is 5.8.
I am new at php world and laravel, thanks for the help!

Comment: how are you returning data to the view? It should be like this `return view('home', $data);`

Comment: sorry i have forget to add that at the question it is as you have said ->   return view('home.home', $data);

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking this down in an easier way for the view to pass.  Use `compact` and be sure to use the string in the compact, not the variable.  Like this:

```
$title  = "Test";
return view('home.home', compact('title');
```

Give that a try, should work fine.

Comment: Or, for the prettier syntax: `return view('home.home')->with('title', $title)`

Comment: Yep that works too, but I like compact a little better for the typical many vars to pass

Answer (score 1):

**Passing Data To Views**

You should pass data in *array with key / value pairs*.
Inside your view, you can then access each value using its corresponding key, such as  `<?php echo $key; ?>`. As an alternative to passing a complete array of data to the view helper function, you may use the `with` method to add individual pieces of data to the view:

```
 return view('home.home')->with('title', 'Test');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views

Answer (score -1):

I have read every answer but every one is missing the magic type to pass the variables to view.

This answer seems to be a bit helpful while **declaring the large number of variable** in the function.

Laravel 5.7.*

For example

```
public function index()
{
    $activePost = Post::where('status','=','active')->get()->count();

    $inActivePost = Post::where('status','=','inactive')->get()->count();

    $yesterdayPostActive = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->addDay(-1))->get()->count();

    $todayPostActive = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->addDay(0))->get()->count();

    return view('dashboard.index')->with('activePost',$activePost)->with('inActivePost',$inActivePost )->with('yesterdayPostActive',$yesterdayPostActive )->with('todayPostActive',$todayPostActive );
}
```

When you see the last line of the returns it not looking good

When your project is getting larger it's not good.

So:

```
public function index()
    {
        $activePost = Post::where('status','=','active')->get()->count();

        $inActivePost = Post::where('status','=','inactive')->get()->count();

        $yesterdayPostActive = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->addDay(-1))->get()->count();

        $todayPostActive = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->addDay(0))->get()->count();

        $viewShareVars = ['activePost','inActivePost','yesterdayPostActive','todayPostActive'];
    
        return view('dashboard.index',compact($viewShareVars));
    }
```

As you see all the variables as declared as array of `$viewShareVars` and accessed in View.

But my function becomes much larger so I have decided to make the line very simple:

```
public function index()
    {
        $activePost = Post::where('status','=','active')->get()->count();

        $inActivePost = Post::where('status','=','inactive')->get()->count();

        $yesterdayPostActive = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->addDay(-1))->get()->count();

        $todayPostActive = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->addDay(0))->get()->count();

        $viewShareVars = array_keys(get_defined_vars());
    
        return view('dashboard.index',compact($viewShareVars));
    }
```

The native PHP function `get_defined_vars()` get all the defined variables from the function and `array_keys` will grab the variable names.

So in your view you can access all the declared variable inside the function as `{{$todayPostActive}}`.

So in your situation:

```
$data['title']   = "Test";

  return view('home.home', compact(array_keys(get_defined_vars())));
```

And in your View `{{$data['title']}}`.